# How far does a rogue move when dashing twice using Cunning Action?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, rogue, actions

A rogue receives a bonus Cunning Action, and one option is to Dash. My understanding is a Dash allows a player to move up to twice his speed for his turn.

If a rogue is using a regular action to Dash (hence, is already dashing) can he also use his cunning action as a bonus to Dash again — effectively moving 4 times normal speed in a turn?

Answer (score 82):

**Cunning Action** absolutely does let you Dash again, but **Dash** doesn't work quite like you're remembering (PHB, p. 192):

> When you take the Dash action, you **gain extra movement** for the current turn. **The increase equals your speed**, after applying any modifiers.

Speed and movement are separate concepts in 5e. Usually your allowed movement for the turn = your speed. Dash doesn't multiply or change your **speed**, it makes your movement this turn = your speed + your speed.

With only one Dash, speed + speed *ends up* the same as speed × 2, but with two Dashes the difference matters, since movement = speed + speed + speed does not equal speed × 4, but equals instead speed × 3.

So yes, you can do this. But you don't move four times your speed, you only move thrice your speed.