# What is the Fastest a Character Can Move in One Turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization, movement

At level 20 with any magic items in the DMG, and any spells, what is the fastest a DnD 5e character could move using their movement?  (i.e., not including teleportation)

Comment: Are other abilities, **magical** items, etc., acceptable, such as a Transmuter's Stone, or do you want to limit this to strictly spells and **magic** items?

Comment: Part of our [fine cheese collection](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7218/23970).

Comment: Ok, there's been a lot of back and forth on whether this question should be closed or not. On the one hand, it's drawn some poor answers, but they're appropriately handled, so I'll just suggest the question stays protected for that reason. And more specific variants of this Q should probably not be closed as a dupe. If there's a further need to close this question, please open a meta, it would be warranted to take that route.

Answer (score 51):

It's [unclear](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/64058/15469) whether bonuses to "your speed" apply to flying speeds. If they **don't**, the fastest you can go is:

- *Shapechange* into a Storm Giant: 50 ft.
- Monk level 15 Unarmored Movement: +25 ft.
- Barbarian level 5 Unarmored Movement: +10 ft.
- Mobile feat: +10 ft.
- *Longstrider* spell: +10 ft.
- Boots of Speed: Double speed
- *Haste* spell: Double speed
- Dash action ×3 (Bonus, Action, and Haste Action): Quadruple speed
- **Total**: (50 + 25 + 10 + 10 + 10) × 2 × 2 × 4 = **1680 ft per round.**

If bonuses to your speed **do** apply to flying speeds then the fastest you can go is:

- *Wind Walk*: 300ft.
- *Longstrider* spell: +10 ft.
- *Haste* spell: Double speed
- *Expeditious Retreat*: Doesn't boost your speed, but allows you to Dash as a bonus action.
- Dash action ×3 (Bonus, Action, and Haste Action): Quadruple speed
- **Total**: (300 + 10) × 2 × 4 = **2480 ft per round.**

Sadly, *Wind Walk* doesn't say anything about letting you benefit from your feats and class features. If it did, you could move at:

- *Wind Walk*: 300 ft.
- Monk level 15 Unarmored Movement: +25 ft.
- Barbarian level 5 Unarmored Movement: +10 ft.
- Mobile feat: +10 ft.
- *Longstrider* spell: +10 ft.
- *Haste* spell: Double speed
- Dash action ×3 (Bonus, Action, and Haste Action): Quadruple speed
- **Total**: (300 + 25 + 10 + 10 + 10) × 2 × 4 = **2840 ft per round.**

Comment: For future readers, to get the maximum speed of any creature with superior speed than a Storm Giant (Volo's _Quickling_, for example), simply multiply their speed by 16, and then add 880.

Comment: I'm not sure that multiple "x2" stack the way you assume. If you have boots of speed and the haste spell, I don't think it's intended to add up to x4, but rather to x3.

Comment: @PixelMaster That's a 3.5e rule that 5e doesn't actually have.

Comment: what's the speed of sound in the d&d world?  because some of these speeds obviously exceed the speed of sound in our own world...

Comment: When factoring your speeds you left out the characters base speed.

Comment: @Michael: 2840 ft/round (where a round is six seconds) is "only" around 323 miles/hour, about half that of the speed of sound (depending on altitude/atmospheric pressure/temperature).

Comment: Maybe 2 Levels of fighter for action surge could be worth it. And 2 Levels of wizard for bladesinging

Comment: Wouldn't it be a net gain to sacrifice two levels of monk for an extra Action Surged dash?

Answer (score 33):

**Solo**

Tabaxi Race (Volo's guide) - 30

5 Barbarian for Fast Movement (PHB) - 10

Elk Totem (SCAG)- 15 (while unencumbered)

5 Monk for Unarmored Movement (PHB) - 10

6 Transmuter Wizard for stone (PHB) - 10

Lvl 1 spell: Longstrider (PHB) - 10

Mobility feat (PHB) - 10

Major artifact with speed (DMG) - 10

Boon of speed (DMG) - 30

**Total = 135**

Tabaxi Feline agility (Volo's guide) - ×2 speed for 1 turn (resets on not moving a turn)

Boots of speed (DMG) - ×2 speed for 10 minutes after bonus action

Lvl 3 spell: Haste - ×2 movement speed

135 × 2 × 2 × 2 = **1080**

Lvl 3 spell: Haste: Dash action - +100% movement

2 Rogue for Cunning action: Dash - +100% movement bonus action

2 Fighter for Action Surge: Dash - +100% movement

Standard Dash action - +100% movement

1080 × 5 = **5400ft for 1 turn**, or ~614mph

If you have help from a transmuter wizard, cut out the 6 wizard levels and give them to Monk for an extra 10ft base, or 80ft per move for an extra 400ft, or 5800ft in one turn

Comment: Note that a Monk can Bonus Dash with the use of 1 ki point, so you don't eed 2 levels of Rogue for this to work.

Comment: This is definite proof that D&D and physics don't mix well :D

Comment: You're only attuned to two items here, you could have another "major artifact with speed" for an extra 10ft movement. As an aside, this requires at least 2 rounds beforehand to cast the spells/click boots/enter rage, and the 15ft from Elk Totem requires you to be raged and in combat (either dealing damage or taking damage) the turn before this speed burst takes place, otherwise rage will end before the turn begins.

Comment: @GaelL Wouldn't the two lvls in rogue invalidate the need for a Ki Dash?

Answer (score 13):

Alright, this is gonna be a process, but I believe I can have a character traveling at **7920 feet per round (900 mph)**, given the absolutely ideal circumstances.

### Base Speed

We'll be going with **Tabaxi** (Volo's Guide to Monsters) for the race, which gives us a base speed of **30 feet**.

Next, we're going to take **10 levels in Monk**, giving us +20 feet from Unarmored Movement, bringing it to **50 feet**. Subclass doesn't matter here, but if we take Way of the Ascendent Dragon (Fizban's Treasury of Dragons), this movement speed can also be flight speed.

We'll take **5 levels in Barbarian**, giving us +10 feet from Fast Movement, bringing it to **60 feet**. We'll go with the **Path of the Totem Warrior** (Player Handbook), specifically choosing the **Elk totem** at 3rd level (Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide), increasing our movement speed by an additional +15 feet when raging, bringing the total to **75 feet**.

Next up, we'll take **2 levels in Wizard**, specifically choosing the **Bladesinging** subclass, giving us another +10 feet from the Bladesong, which doesn't require concentration, meaning it can be done at the same time as the Barbarian's rage. Along with the **Longstrider** spell, which adds an additional +10 feet, lasts for an hour, and also is not concentration, this brings our total so far to **95 feet**.

Next, we're going to make sure we have the **Mobile feat**, adding an additional +10 feet to our movement speed, and we're going to attune to two different **artifacts** that each have the Major Beneficial Property of adding +10 feet to our movement speed. This will bring us to a base movement speed of **125 feet**.

We need a friend who happens to be a **6th level Transmutation Wizard** (Player Handbook), who then gives us their **Transmuter's Stone**, increasing our speed by another +10 feet, bringing the total to **135 feet**.

Last but not least, we're going to take **2 levels in Fighter** and **1 level in Sorcerer**, choosing the **Wild Magic** subclass (Player Handbook), but most importantly for now, that will bring us to level 20, making the **Boon of Speed** (Chapter 7: Other Rewards, Dungeon Master's Guide) available to us, adding an additional +30 feet, which brings our grand total base movement speed to **165 feet**.

### Multipliers

First off, we're going to use our third attunement slot to get some **Boots of Speed**, which allow us to double our movement speed.

Then, we're going to have our Transmutation Wizard friend cast **Haste** on us, doubling our movement speed again, and giving us an additional action to work with later.

Lastly, we're going to use the **Feline Agility** trait that the Tabaxi has to double our speed a third time. All of these abilities don't just increase our speed (like the dash actions does), but actually double it, bringing our grand total movement speed to **1320 feet per round**.

### Dashing

Now comes the fun. With our movement speed of **1320 feet per round**, we're going to dash using every available action we have.

We can use our initial action, our bonus action (Step of the Wind), our Hasted action, and an action surge to take one more, thanks to our 2 levels in fighter.

Additionally, we're going to play with probability here and use our level in Wild Magic Sorcerer. If we have a **Wild Magic Surge** and roll **01-02** on the table, that means we roll on the table at the start of each of our turns for the next minute. If we get extraordinarily lucky, we'll roll **81-82**, which requires us to take an additional action immediately. We can use this additional action to add one extra dash onto the pile.

### Recap

Race: Tabaxi

Levels:

- 10 Monk (Way of the Ascendent Dragon)
- 5 Barbarian (Path of the Totem Warrior)
- 2 Wizard (Bladesinging)
- 2 Fighter
- 1 Sorcerer (Wild Magic)

Base Speed & Modifiers:

- 30 feet
- +20 (Unarmored Movement, Monk)
- +10 (Fast Movement, Barbarian)
- +15 (Elk Totem, Barbarian)
- +10 (Bladesong, Wizard)
- +10 (Longstrider Spell, Wizard)
- +10 (Mobile feat.)
- +10 (Major Beneficial Property Artifact)
- +10 (Major Beneficial Property Artifact)
- +10 (Transmuter's Stone)
- +30 Boon of Speed

Multipliers:

- Haste Spell x2
- Boots of Speed x2
- Feline Agility x2

Dashes:

- Base Movement Speed
- Action
- Bonus Action (Step of the Wind)
- Hasted Action
- Action Surge
- Wild Magic Action

### **1320 x 6 = 7920 feet per round or 900 mph**

Comment: Great post - but dash adds your current speed to your curent available movement. It does not double your current available movement or change your speed.  https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57340/how-far-does-a-rogue-move-when-dashing-twice-using-cunning-action/57342#57342

Comment: @ArtickokeAndAnchovyPizzaMonica I don't think Oneroni13 has made that mistake, you can see they total up 1320ft speed, then multiply it by 6 because they move once and take dash 5x (action, bonus action, hasted action, action surge, and wild magic action).

Answer (score 5):

Tabaxi (from *Volo's Guide to Monsters*)
Monk 18 / fighter 2

60ft
+10 ft longstrider
+10 ft transmuter stone
+10 ft mobile

90  ×2 tabaxi
 180 ×2 haste
 360 ×2 boots of speed
=720ft

720  Move
 1440 Action
 2160 Bonus action
 2880 Haste action
 3600 Action surge

That's a total of 3600 ft in 1 round.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and this looks like a good catch. But I'm not sure I'm following a few things: "1440 Action" is Dash? What's the bonus action you're taking? And then is "2880 Haste action" the Dash granted by *haste*? Lastly, I think it'd be nice for you to cite where you get the Tabaxi race--since it's not a race in the core set I think it's reasonable to assume some future readers may not be aware of their racial trait as regards movement.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I think I have calculated the fastest a character can move in ideal conditions without teleporting. Bear with me, as it's pretty contrived. I am interpreting increases to "speed" to apply to all speeds, whereas I am interpreting increases to "walking speed" to only apply to walking speed, so we need to find the fastest walking speed we can.

Edit: as [@David Coffron](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/41726/david-coffron) mentioned, it works to use *Shapechange* instead of Wild Shape: you still keep your class and racial features, and this character is capable of casting it from a Level 9 Spell Scroll with their Wizard levels (and with an Intelligence ability check of 19, but let's assume we make that). *Shapechange* is concentration, and is Target: self, so if we want *Haste* too we will need to have it cast on this character or use a Potion of Speed. As such we can remove the Druid levels and take more Monk, boosting the character's speed even higher.

### Base Speed

- **Race: Tabaxi**, base 30ft walking speed, Feline Agility feature.
- **Barbarian (Totem Warrior: Elk) 5**: +10 speed from Fast Movement, +15 walking speed from Totem Spirit: Elk. (Needs to be raging for Elk Totem Spirit: do this as a bonus action on an earlier round, and make sure you keep your rage going until you can pull this turn off.)
- **Fighter 2**: Action Surge.
- **Monk 10**: +20 speed from Unarmored Movement.
- **Sorcerer (Wild Magic) 1**: Wild Magic Surge. (This helps us, but requires casting a leveled spell and getting very lucky! See below in the Setup section.)
- **Wizard (Bladesinging) 2**: Spellcasting (for the spell scroll) and Bladesong, +10 walking speed. (Use a bonus action to activate on an earlier turn.)
- This takes us to **Level 20** to get Epic Boons.
- **Mobile feat**: +10 speed.
- **Boon of Speed**: +30 walking speed, bonus action dash once per short rest.
- ***Shapechange* spell active**: *Shapechange* into a quickling with base 120ft walking speed. Cast *Shapechange* with a Level 9 spell scroll using your 2 levels in Wizard, make the DC 19 Intelligence ability check, and make sure you maintain concentration.
- ***Longstrider* spell active**: +10 speed. (Not concentration; cast it on yourself with your Wizard levels or have your friendly Wizard cast it on you.)
- **Artifact 1 (1st attuned) with two major properties of speed**: +20 walking speed.
- **Artifact 2 (2nd attuned) with two major properties of speed**: +20 walking speed.
- **An ally Artificer (Alchemist)** with the Level 3 feature Experimental Elixir and a bit of luck gets you Swiftness, +10 walking speed.
- **2x ally Fighter (Battle Master)** at level 3 for maneuvers, or anyone with the Martial Adept feat who has access to Maneuvering Attack: A friendly creature who can see or hear you can use its reaction to move up to half its speed. Having two is very important to allow us to use a reaction before our turn and a reaction after our turn, getting us two in one round.
- **An ally Paladin (Oath of Glory)** with the Level 7 feature Aura of Alacrity: +10 walking speed.
- **An ally Wizard (Transmutation)** with the level 6 feature Transmuter's Stone: +10 speed.
- ***Haste* spell active**: x2 speed, hasted action Dash. (Concentration, and 3rd level; have your friendly Wizard cast it on you.)
- **Boots of Speed (3rd attunement)**: x2 walking speed. (Use a bonus action to activate this on a previous turn.)

All up, this gives us a base walking speed for the round of [120 (quickling) + 10 (Barbarian Fast Movement) + 15 (Totem Spirit Elk) + 20 (Monk 10 Unarmored Movement) + 10 (Bladesong) + 10 (Mobile) + 30 (Boon of Speed) + 10 (*Longstrider*) + 20 (Artifact 1) + 20 (Artifact 2) + 10 (Experimental Elixir) + 10 (Aura of Alacrity) + 10 (Transmuter's Stone)] x 2 (*Haste*) x 2 (Boots of Speed) = **1180ft**.

### Setup

As mentioned, on previous rounds we want to have used our action to cast *Shapechange* into a quickling, a bonus action to rage to activate Elk Totem Spirit, an action or bonus action to cast a leveled Sorcerer spell to activate Wild Magic Surge, a bonus action to trigger Bladesong, and a bonus action to trigger the Boots of Speed's doubling effect. We also need to have *Longstrider* and *Haste* active and be within 5ft of the ally Paladin with Aura of Alacrity. For the Wild Magic Surge (thanks [@oneroi13](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/73986/oneroi13) for spelling this out in [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58632/what-is-the-fastest-a-character-can-move-in-one-turn#answer-193016)!) we need the DM to cooperate, having us roll after casting the leveled spell, then either roll a 1 on a d20 to trigger a Wild Magic Surge or trigger it automatically with Tides of Chaos, then get a 01-02 on 1d100 on the Wild Magic Surge Table to trigger "Roll on this table at the start of each of your turns for the next minute, ignoring this result on subsequent rolls."

### The Round

Then, we need the round to progress like this:

- Our ally Battle Master Fighter or whoever has Maneuvering Strike moves before us in initiative, hits a creature with a weapon attack, and triggers Maneuvering Strike from a place we can see or hear them, allowing us to use our reaction to move up to half our speed (590ft).
- At the start of the turn we pull this off roll 81-82 on 1d100 on the Wild Magic Surge Table to trigger "You can take one additional action immediately."
- Then we activate the Tabaxi feature Feline Agility: "Your reflexes and agility allow you to move with a burst of speed. When you move on your turn in combat, you can double your speed until the end of the turn. Once you use this trait, you can't use it again until you move 0 feet on one of your turns." This doubles our speed again to 2360ft.
- Then we Move, use our action to Dash, use our bonus action to Dash (from the Boon of Speed – or using a Ki point to use the Monk's Step of the Wind, which we also have), use our hasted action to Dash, use Action Surge and use that action to Dash, and use our extra action from Wild Magic Surge to Dash. That's 6 moves at 2360ft each, so 2360*6 = 14160ft.
- We end our turn within sight or hearing range of our second ally Battle Master Fighter, who luckily moves after us in initiative. We have our reaction back, so on their turn they hit a creature with a weapon attack, and trigger Maneuvering Strike from a place we can see or hear them, allowing us to use our reaction again to move up to half our speed. Unfortunately Feline Agility wore off at the end of our turn, so that's only another 590 ft.

In total that round, that's **14160 + 590*2 = 15340ft** over 6 seconds, or 1400 miles per hour – just over Mach 2.3. So you can expect sonic booms as you move! Admittedly, the question was only about how fast you can move on your turn, so that's just **14160ft** over 6 seconds, which is only slightly slower, and you can forgo the complex positioning with the two Battle Masters.

---

### Caveats

I looked into making this work with *Wind Walk*, as the base 300ft move would be incredibly useful. Unfortunately, it is too hard to boost without any of the features that increase walking speed. I did manage to get it up to **7920ft** per round, and you can still do the Battle Master cheese, but unfortunately the Boots of Speed only apply to walking speed, and without that doubling it is not quite enough to match what I've laid out above.

[@Ibenadar](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users/34015/ibenadar) mentioned the 303 Monk in [this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/58632/what-is-the-fastest-a-character-can-move-in-one-turn#answer-94712) which can supposedly move at 16800ft per round while *Wind Walk*ing, and looking into it, it seems to assume that all increases to speed or walking speed stack on top of *Wind Walk*'s base speed. I don't think that's reasonable, at the very least given how *Wind Walk* specifies flying speed while e.g. the Boon of Speed explicitly only boosts walking speed, so while it's a bit faster than what I've given, I don't think it's actually attainable.

Admittedly, a lot of this is subject to the DM. As mentioned right at the beginning, I am using a specific interpretation where features that add to "speed" add to all base speeds (walking, flying, climbing, swimming, burrowing etc), whereas features that add to "walking speed" only add to the walking speed. Whether bonuses to "speed" are only meant to apply to walking speed is contentious and unclear, but I am going with the Crawford clarification that bonuses to speed apply to all speeds. Further discussion [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/64053/does-wind-soul-storm-sorcerer-stack-with-the-mobile-feat/64058#64058).

It also depends on the DM allowing rolling for a Wild Magic Surge, which should be pretty reasonable but isn't a guarantee (and then the incredible luck getting the right Wild Magic Surge afterwards, though that isn't DM-dependent). More pressingly, it also depends on attuning to two artifacts both of which have 2 major beneficial properties to speed. Artifacts are only meant to be made by the gods so it's entirely up to the DM whether the required artifacts exist at all. After this, it's also unclear whether a single major beneficial property of speed is a unique magical effect and whether they stack – if the DM rules that they don't that reduces our artifact speed bonus by 30ft.

Lastly, we are getting a lot of mileage (lol) from the Tabaxi's Feline Agility racial feature. It is very questionable whether that still works when Wild Shaped or Shapechanged: you keep class and racial features, but only if the new form is physically capable of doing so. Unfortunately, Feline Agility has the barest minimum of fluff: "Your reflexes and agility allow you to move with a burst of speed." So it's unclear if it should work only on creatures that are sufficiently similar to Tabaxi (as it's a Tabaxi racial feature), creatures that are sufficiently feline (from the name Feline Agility) or any creatures that are sufficiently agile. This ruling is also very dependent on the DM, and losing that doubling will reduce the maximum speed quite significantly, so it's important to consider that if anyone is bold enough to try this in an actual game.

### Result

Assuming all my assumptions hold, based on the above calculations the quickest a character can travel without teleporting in a single round is **15340ft**, or **14160ft** just on their turn. With a lot of luck for the Wild Magic shenanigans, Experimental Elixir of Swiftness and ally positioning, but it still gets you there!

Comment: Using legendary *spell scrolls*, you could use *shapechange* (a quickling is the fastest walking speed option) without needing to invest heavily in wizard.

Comment: Huh, I think that would work. That would let us drop the levels in Druid and get 4 more Monk, which gives +5 more base speed. You'd need to get lucky casting from the scroll but it's not like it's any more contrived than the Wild Magic shenanigans we have already. I'll edit in *shapechange* -> quickling and see what that gives us.

Answer (score 1):

Wood Elf: 35ft Base walking speed

Monk 12 / Fighter 2 / Barbarian 6

**Bonuses**

Monk 12: Unarmored Speed +20

Barbarian 6: Fast Movement +10 and with Eagle Totems, you can Dash as a bonus action without using Ki and enemies have disadvantage on opportunity attacks

Fighter 2: Action Surge

Transmuter's Stone: +10

Mobile Feat: +10

Longstrider: +10

Haste: Double Speed

Boots of Speed: Double Speed

**Results**

Speed = (35 + 20 + 10 + 10 + 10 + 10) × 2 × 2

Movement Speed with buffs: 380ft

Move 5 times on your turn (Dash, Dash with Bonus Action, Dash with Haste Action, Dash using Action Surge, Movement Action)

That's 1900ft per round, or about 215 mph.

I rest my case.

Answer (score -1):

The fastest single round movement speed is one of 3 answers. The fastest is the 303-Monk which has to be lightly beaten until launch.

Using a friendly Transmuter plus magic item property rules - 16,800 feet flying, but all you can do is move and it also requires a friendly Transmuter to flog until ready to maintain Rage whilst the Abjurer Ward covers the HP damage. The 303-Monk covers 3.03miles at Mach 2.37 and is quite angry when it arrives.

Using a friendly Transmuter and only the printed magic items - 16,000 flying

Just by themselves means losing Elk Rage and dropping Monk FM to +10 - 15,400 flying or 14,800 if we forego the Magic Item qualities too

Just by themselves and no Wind Walk has a different build utilizing Druid Wild Shaping and Potion of Speed. This gets - Land 6,800, Swimming 6,800, Climbing 6,000, Burrowing 5,000, Potion of Flying 6,800

Same Druid, but no +5 or +10 speed magic items - 6,200/6,200/5,400/4,400/6,200

Fastest Speed Build - Solo and no Wind Walk
Tabaxi - Wizard 7, Barbarian 5, Druid 4, Fighter 2, Rogue 2
Race - Double speed
Feats - Mobile +10
Class - Barbarian Elk Rage +15, Barbarian Fast Movement +10, Fighter Action Surge +Dash, Cunning Action +Dash
Spells - Longstrider +10, Potion of Speed +Dash & Double Speed, Wind Walk 300ft speed
Objects - Boots of Speed Double Speed, +5 Minor Magic Item Quality, +10 Major Magic Item Quality, +10 Transmuter, Potion of Flying
Boon - Speed +30

Base Movement: 170 feet
60 +10+15+10+10+10+5+10+10+30

Speed Multipliers: 1,360 feet
Boots x2
Haste x2
Tabaxi x2

Number of Moves: 5 x 1,360 = 6,800
Move = 1
Action +1
Bonus (ER or CA) +1
Haste Extra Action +1
Action Surge +1

Fastest Speed Build - Wind Walk + Friendly Transmuter
Tabaxi - Rogue 2, Fighter 2, Elk-Barbarian 5, Monk 11
Race - Double speed
Feats - Mobile +10
Class - Barbarian Elk Rage +15 [walking only], Barbarian Fast Movement +10, Fighter Action Surge +Dash, Monk Unarmored Movement +20
Spells - Cunning Action +Dash, Longstrider +10, Haste +Dash & Double Speed, Wind Walk 300ft speed [unlcear: "While in this cloud form, a creature has a flying speed of 300 feet" - that wording implies that your fly speed DECREASES to 300 if its more than that.]
Objects - Boots of Speed Double Speed [walking only], +5 Minor Magic Item Quality[if you make your own], +10 Major Magic Item Quality [if you make your own], +10 Transmuter
Boon - Speed +30

Base Movement: 420 feet
300 +10+15+10+20+10+5+10+10+30  (Mobile+Elk Rage+Longstrider+Unarmored Monk+Major Magic+Minor Magic+Barbarian Fast Movement+Transmuter Stone+Epic Boon)

Speed Multipliers: 3,360 feet
Boots x2
Haste x2
Tabaxi x2

Number of Moves: 5 x 3,360 = 16,800
Move = 1
Action +1
Bonus (CA) +1
Haste Extra Action +1
Action Surge +1

Comment: I'm curious, how did you get base movement up to 420? I only managed to get up to 415 using wind walk. (I went fighter 2/barbarian 5/monk 10/ranger 3 as a tabaxi with boon of speed, longstrider, transmuter stone, mobile feat, haste, and wind walk. wind walk starts us at 300 adding longstrider, the transmuter stone, and the mobile feat adds +30, +20 from monk, barbarian 5 gives us +10 and another +15 while raging, boon of speed adds +30, and ranger adds +10 totaling at 415)

Answer (score -2):

Wood Elf: 35ft speed

Monk level 15 Unarmored Movement: +25 ft.

Barbarian level 5 Unarmored Movement: +10 ft.

Mobile feat: +10 ft

Longstrider spell: +10 ft

Boots of Speed: Double speed

Haste Spell: Double speed

Dash Action x3 (Bonus, Action, and Haste Action): Quadruple speed

Total: (35+25+10+10+10) × 2 × 2 × 4 = **1440 feet per round**

Answer (score -2):

Found the ultimate build for speed:

Race: Tabaxi
Barbarian: Path of the Totem Warrior 5
Monk: Drunken 10th
Ranger: Gloom Stalker: 3rd
Wizard: Bladesinging: 2nd

Feat: Mobile

Magic Item: Elixer of Swiftness
Magic Item: Boots of speed

Spell: Haste

Start turn within Paladin Aura of Alacrity

Epic Boon of Speed

1 Round: 1 Mile!! Yep that is 5280 feet in 1 round however unlikely

Comment: Can you add more detail for how you get that speed? break down each benefit for your answer.

Answer (score -3):

I know I'm super late to this post, but here goes nothing.

My fastest speed build is as follows (using only what is listed in RAW, as well as 1 factor of presumed RAI, being that Dashing multiple times doubles speed each time, the reason for that assumption is that 5e is awful with wording sometime, and it seems to me that movement and speed are interchangeable, as some spells see them as such).

Keep in mind, that the wording of the Dash action states that it includes modifiers to your speed, which would include other iterations of the Dash action. This build also requires two friends, one magic item, and 2 total turns to do.

**Tabaxi** (30 base speed)

**Mobile feat** (+10 base speed, now total of 40)

**Monk 18** (+30 base speed now total of 70, subclass is up to player choice)

**Fighter 2**

**Longstrider spell from a friend** (+10 base speed, now total of 80)

**Haste spell from a friend** (for double speed and extra Dash action)

**Boots of Speed** (for double speed)

**Turn 1:** Friends cast Haste and Longstrider on you, you use your Bonus Action to activate the Boots of Speed (base speed on your own of 70, now has +10 from Longstrider and is doubled from both Haste and the Boots for total of 320 ([70+10] * 2 * 2))

**Turn 2** Your current base speed is 320 (see the math above). Dash Action (640), Step of the Wind for Bonus Action Dash (1280), Action Surge Dash (2560), Feline Agility (5120), Haste Action Dash (10240).

This build already requires two other people's effects, or I would've included a Transmuter's Stone. The goal in this is to maintain fairness, because there is no guarantee that you would have a Transmutation Wizard, but it is highly likely to have allies who can cast Haste and Longstrider. The math (if this was maintained over time, which it cannot be, due to spell length and such), is as follows: 10240 * 10 (feet per minute) = 102400 * 60 (feet per hour) = 6144000/5280 (miles per hour) = 1163.63636 miles per hour.

Sorry if this is disorganized, not the best at that kind of thing.

Comment: Dash adds your current speed to your curent available movement. It does not double your current available movement or change your speed.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Yes. It adds your current speed to your available movement. Which is a modifier to your speed, which Dash also adds to your available movement.

Comment: No, available movement and speed are not the same thing. If I move 30 feet, I have 0 available movement, but then if I take the dash action, I get 30 feet of movement back. *My speed was 30 feet the whole time*.

Comment: "When you take the Dash action, you gain extra movement for the current turn. The increase equals your speed, after applying any modifiers. With a speed of 30 feet, for example, you can move up to 60 feet on your turn if you dash.

Any increase or decrease to your speed changes this additional movement by the same amount. If your speed of 30 feet is reduced to 15 feet, for instance, you can move up to 30 feet this turn if you dash."

Page 192 of the Player's Handbook.

Comment: That is correct, you gain extra movement, not "you gain extra speed".

Comment: This answer explains in more detail why you're answer here is incorrect: [How far does a rogue move when dashing twice using Cunning Action?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/57342)

Comment: Fair enough, I will update my post to accommodate. Thanks for the feedback!

Comment: The answer should identify which ruling here is your "presumed RAI", and it would be helpful to include some support for why you are presuming that.

Answer (score -4):

Mine is without Shapeshifting, and is going to ignore being a Wood Elf, because Wood Elf obviously will move faster

13 Monk, 5 Barbarian, 2 Rogue

30ft base speed
10ft Mobility feat
10 ft Barbarian feature
20 ft Monk feature
30 ft Boon of Speed (character is level 20 so if DM allows it Boons can be a thing. in the DMG)
10ft longstrider

Boots of speed = x2
Haste = x2

this all totals out to (30+10+10+20+30+10) * 4 = 440ft movement

As for Moves per turn

Regular Move
Action (Dash)
Haste (Dash)
Cunning Action (Dash)
Monk's Step of Wind, Bonus Action (Dash)

This is 5 moves, so 440*5 = 2200ft in 6 seconds, which is 250mph

Comment: You've got too many bonus actions in there: Cunning action lets you Dash with a bonus action, and then you've got another "Bonus Action (Dash)" in your list. Only one bonus action per turn, though.