# What is the number of Temporary HP you get from Wizard's Arcane Ward?

Tags: dnd-5e, wizard, temporary-hit-points

I'm playing D&D 5e as a DM for about a 3-4 sessions now and the math involved in the Wizard's ability *Arcane Ward* is a little unclear to me. All of my players just reached level 2 and one of the players is a Wizard who chose *The School of Abjuration* archetype and he now has the *Arcane Ward* ability.

Playing by the PHB(p.109) the ability states:

> Starting at 2nd level, you can weave magic around yourself for
>   protection. When you cast an abjuration spell of 1st level or higher,
>   you can simultaneously use a strand of the spell's magic to create a
>   magical ward on yourself that lasts until you finish a long rest. **The**
>   **ward has hit points equal to twice your wizard level + your**
>   **Intelligence modifier.**

With his Intelligence modifier (+3) and Wizard level 2 the equation should be:

$$
\begin{align}
{Temporary\;HP} &= ( 2 \times {Wizard\;level} ) + {Int\;modifier} \\
&= ( 2 \times 2 ) + 3 \\
&= 4 + 3 \\
&= 7
\end{align}
$$

But it can also be:

$$
\begin{align}
{Temporary\;HP} &= 2 \times ( {Wizard\;level} + {Int\;modifier} ) \\
&= 2 \times ( 2 + 3 ) \\
&= 2 \times 5 \\
&= 10
\end{align}
$$

The text makes it unclear.

Comment: Related: [How are numerical bonuses combined?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83663/how-are-numerical-bonuses-combined)

Comment: @Spellcaster Related links are just meant to help people who may be interested in related questions. They aren't meant to imply that they are the same as yours.

Comment: @PixelMaster See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your second comment was removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

### 7 HP

As [Rykara's answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/138815/28591) states, the amount of HP the ward has should be 7.  The relevant [quote from Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/765984419945390080) is:

> Arcane Ward—its hit point maximum equals your Intelligence modifier plus twice your wizard level.

### But they are not temporary hit points

But it is important to note that these are ***not*** Temporary Hit Points.

According to [Sage Advice](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/sageadvice_july2015),

> An Arcane Ward is not an extension of the wizard who creates it. It is a magical effect with its own hit points. Any temporary hit points, immunities, or resistances that the wizard has don’t apply to the ward.
>
> The ward takes damage first. Any leftover damage is taken by the
> wizard and goes through the following game elements in order: (1) any
> relevant damage immunity, (2) any relevant damage resistance, (3) any
> temporary hit points, and (4) real hit points.

In other words, the ward has 7 of its own Hit Points and the Wizard can still benefit from Temporary Hit Points from another source.

Answer (score 2):

### 7 HP

Jeremy Crawford has [clarified on Twitter](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/765984419945390080?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw%7Ctwcamp%5Etweetembed%7Ctwterm%5E765984419945390080&ref_url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sageadvice.eu%2F2016%2F09%2F28%2Fis-abjurers-arcane-ward-2%2F):

> Arcane Ward—its hit point maximum equals your Intelligence modifier plus twice your wizard level.

Comment: You are going to want to clarify that OP is making an incorrect assumption in the question: these are not temp HP. Currently your answer seems to be reaffirming that incorrect belief.