# Can multiple enemies in one round pass by a PC, attack, and keep moving?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, actions, attack

Can multiple creatures go through a 5' space next to a PC and deliver attacks as they pass the PC? (The creatures all have the same initiative, if that matters.) i.e.:

1. Move
2. Attack PC
3. Move to the limit of their movement

Comment: related, possible duplicate: [how many creatures can attack a single creature...](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/93892/23970)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Yes, this is a legitimate series of events

Creatures are allowed to break up their movement and attack throughout it - including managing multiple attacks if that is an option. This can be found in the PHB on page 190.

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using some of your speed before and after your action...If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks.

Multiple creatures doing this in a row doesn't change this. That's just a function of their turn in the initiative order (even if they all have the same initiative spot), so that's also working as designed in that series of events.

**Note**: The PC that is 'guarding' the door only get 1 Opportunity Attack. The remaining creatures will be able to walk by safely once that is spent.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes, but be aware of the danger.**

Moving attacking and then moving is a valid sequence of events.  The fact that there are multiple creatures attempting to deliver attacks in passing on a single PC is irrelevant.

According to the basic rules

> You can break up your movement on your turn, using  some of your speed
>   before and after your action. For  example, if you have a speed of 30
>   feet, you can move  10 feet, take your action, and then move 20 feet.

But, keep in mind that by engaging with the PC they invite one opportunity attack as they try to leave his attack range.

From the [Basic Rules, p74](http://media.wizards.com/2016/downloads/DND/PlayerBasicRulesV03.pdf#page=74):

> You can make an opportunity attack when a hostile creature that you
>   can see moves out of your reach. To make the opportunity attack, you
>   use your reaction to make one melee attack against the provoking
>   creature. The attack interrupts the provoking creature’s movement,
>   occurring right before the creature leaves your reach.

[Reaction Rules:](https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/5e_SRD:Reactions)

> When you take a reaction, you can’t take another one until the start
>   of your next turn. If the reaction interrupts another creature’s turn,
>   that creature can continue its turn right after the reaction.

Comment: "by engaging with the PC they invite one opportunity attack" - it’s a little unclear if you are saying each enemy invites an opportunity attack or "they" as a team invite one. A PC can only make one opportunity attack between turns, os it's not a lot of danger to a mob of baddies.