# Does the Primeval Guardian ranger's reach increase stack with the Mystic's Giant Growth discipline and a reach weapon?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranger, unearthed-arcana, reach, mystic

Say I am a 4th level [Primeval Guardian Ranger](https://media.wizards.com/2016/dnd/downloads/2017_01_UA_RangerRogue_0117JCMM.pdf), and 4th level [Mystic](https://media.wizards.com/2017/dnd/downloads/UAMystic3.pdf).

The [**Glaive**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/glaive) has the Reach property, which increases its reach by 5 feet.

The Primeval Guardian ranger gets the **Guardian Soul** feature, which has the following effects (among others):

- Your size becomes Large, unless you were larger.
- Your reach increases by 5 feet.

The mystic can learn the **Giant Growth psionic discipline**, which has the following benefits:

- Psychic Focus: While focused on this discipline, your reach increases by 5 feet.
- Ogre Form (costs 2 psi points; duration of concentration, up to a minute) has the following benefits, among others: Your reach increases by 5 feet. If you're smaller than Large, you also become Large for the duration.

**Does this image accurately depict the overall reach?**

[image]

I'm not sure if this is how it works, nut it seems like a lot of fun to mess around with if it stacks like this. Even if you can only move 5 feet per turn, having a reach of 20 feet is interesting.

Comment: Related: [What build maximizes reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/what-build-maximizes-reach)

Comment: Your image has a few typos: "Guradian" and "Orge". (Also, I've just done a bunch of copyediting on the question itself and edited the title to clarify what you're asking.)

Comment: It is important to note that [Unearthed Arcana material is **not tuned for multiclassing**](https://twitter.com/jeremyecrawford/status/791048635815301120).

Answer (score 6):

### This works, but your graphic is slightly inaccurate.

> 1 square of movement left, even if the square is diagonally adjacent to the square you’re in.

The [variant rules on grid-based combat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#SqueezingintoaSmallerSpace) treat diagonal movement as equivalent to horizontal or vertical movement, which means a 25 foot reach would be shown as squares like so:

[image]

Otherwise, **the effects of each of these *do* stack since they simply state that your reach is increasing by 5** (not that your reach is set to 10 feet). Therefore, your dreams of the out-ranging a 30-foot poll are only a bit further away (The Bugbear race or 3 levels in Way of the Four Elements Monk to be exact).

Comment: Good answer. Is it worth pointing out that although they would stack, none of these options have been play balanced for official play yet, and normally this sort of synergy would be caught before publication? I.e., yes it works, but it's unlikely that it would in final form?

Comment: @keithcurtis You can get close to that synergy in official play too (*enlarge person* on a bugbear or wild shape into a giant octopus). I think if these features are released they will stay in this form (although I think Mystic will receive an overhaul meaning the features may not even be present)

Comment: @keithcurtis none of this causes any balance issues. Doing _more_ damage is problematic, not doing the same from furher. Otherwise we should ban bows and ranged spells.

Comment: Using a grid is a variant rule, as you say yourself. Under the default rules, the concentric circles are entirely correct.

Comment: @MarkWells But the concentric circles are.... well on a grid. I figured it was fair to assume grid rules were in play

Comment: @DavidCoffron Yeah, that's fair.

Comment: @András missile weapons cannot do opportunity attacks. This amount of reach could be devastating with the Sentinel feat, for instance. All I'm saying is to beware of unofficial builds, particularly when looking for combos, since those usually come towards the end of the design phase.

Comment: @keithcurtis Sentinel uses up your reaction, so still only works once per round. Also the most potent feature (3rd bullet point) explicitly work only in 5 feet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

Quite simply:

> Your reach increases by 5 feet

Means your reach increases by 5 feet. I don't know of any more specific rule that denies this build so it works.

Comment: ... if your DM allows you to use Unearthed Arcana classes in this way.

Comment: @Mark Wells I figured that was an assumption that could be made... If your dm disallows unearthed arcana then this doesn't exist, but if they do allow it then it does work.

Comment: "Allowing Unearthed Arcana" doesn't mean allowing every bizarre thing someone might try to do with Unearthed Arcana. If you're going to try this specific trick then you should clear it with your DM in advance, or else you're going to be awfully disappointed when they say "No."