# Can you use a reach weapon to make the bonus-action attack granted by the Charger feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, attack, reach, melee-combat

The [Charger](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/charger) feat (PHB, p. 165) says:

> When you use your action to Dash, you can use a bonus action to make one melee weapon attack or to shove a creature.
>
> If you move at least 10 feet in a straight line immediately before taking this bonus action, you either gain a +5 bonus to the attack’s damage roll (if you chose to make a melee attack and hit) or push the target up to 10 feet away from you (if you chose to shove and you succeed).

Can you use a reach weapon to make the bonus-action attack granted by the Charger feat?

I'm wondering about making one melee attack with a pike, after moving the required 10 feet. Example: The foe is 40 feet away; I Dash 30 feet towards him in a straight line with my action, and then I make a melee attack with my bonus action, using the pike's 10-foot reach.

(I'm not asking about the shove option for the bonus action - simply the first part about using a bonus action to make one melee attack.)

Comment: Is there a reason you think this wouldn't work?

Comment: Use a melee weapon attack.  
I'm trying to clarify if I have to "Charge" into 5ft range, even if I don't want to shove, or as long as I've used the Dash action and moved 10ft in a straight line I can stop 10ft away from an enemy and apply the +5 to a bonus action melee attack as per the Charger feat

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming there is no other effect in play...

## Yes, you can use a reach weapon for this attack.

You may dash, move (at least) 10 feet, and then use Charger's bonus action attack while using a reach weapon and gain the +5 bonus damage.

Charger doesn't say "make an attack against an opponent within 5 feet of you" or something similar; as long as you meet the requirements needed to make a melee weapon attack after the required movement, you're good to go.

This even works if you employ any of the various reach techniques outlined in this question:
[What build maximizes reach?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111256/what-build-maximizes-reach)