# How fast can a char be?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I aways liked speed characters like Speed-o'-Sound Sonic from One punch man, that moves fast, attacks fast, etc ...

The question is, how can I create one of these on D&D?

Seems impossible to me, prove me wrong please.

Comment: Welcome! Optimization questions like this are fine but you should probably focus on either movement speed or number of attacks. Specifying more conditions such as if you are interested in fastest moving in a single round or several per day, whether other characters helping is allowed. See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/103181/33707) as an example. Good luck and happy gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance. As Sdjz said, we can help you build/optimize a character to maximize a certain aspect of their abilities, but we need a lot more specific information from you about the character (what level they are, anything you definitely want or don't want on the character, what aspect of "speed characters" is most important to you, etc.). If you provide this information, we might be able to reopen the question and answer it. Also, the question in the title is totally different from the one in the body.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/14505/4563).

Comment: If the duplicate linked does not answer the question you have, please [edit] this post to make clearer exactly what you're looking for, then flag the post for reopening. Thanks!