# What's the biggest choir I can create within 24 hours?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

So I kind of forgot that tomorrow is the birthday of my [dear mother-in-law](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/161208/whats-the-greatest-number-of-hands-i-can-have-to-annoy-my-mother-in-law-with), and I (stupidly in hindsight) promised I would show her "the biggest choir anyone could ever make, no humans required". So now I have 24 hours left before she arrives to see the choir I promised her, I really need to do something and gather as many non-humans (read: non-humanoids) with the time I have left - and give them each a paper with the lyrics of the song we will perform. After all, if I have to fulfill this promise I will do it my way - with gruesome melodies straight from hell.

The following rules apply:

- Only officially published materials
- You can only use summoned or conjured creatures in your choir, and you or your summoned creatures can not interact with creatures you have not summoned or conjured yourself
- Creatures must not be of the creature type "humanoid"
- Up to 20 levels at your disposal
- Multiclassing allowed
- Feats and Magic Items are available as needed
- Unlimited money
- Creatures have to speak at least one language, though being fluent is Abyssal is not required
- Time Limit: 24 hours
- The sheets with the lyrics would need to be created as well, you have one copy on a piece of paper yourself
- The choir must be able to perform at least 1 minute continously, if it last longer a nice addition

Comment: Possible start of an answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/79841/11358

Comment: Would animating creatures/objects, instead of summoning/conjuring them, also be allowed for this choir?

Comment: Yes, e.g. Animate Objects, Create Undead etc. are all vaild to use. Just no living humanoids.

Comment: @TobiasF. Can those even sing?

Comment: @EkadhSingh-ReinstateMonica The objects not so much, the undead? I'd have to check the statblocks if the can speak. But it ismore to show the general idea of things / spells you could use. Conjure Woodland Beings could also work etc.

Comment: Woodland Beings singing Happy Birthday? Are we running  Disney RPG here?

Comment: @DJClayworth Not quite happy birthday but more some tunes that cause most creatures to scream "Demos! Begone Fiend!" when they hear it ;)

Comment: So definitely Disney then.

Comment: Can you clarify "...**you or your summoned creatures can not interact with creatures you have not summoned or conjured yourself**"? What would prevent you from interacting with anything? And for all the summoned things, what would forbid them from interacting with their environment other than a stern "No!"?

Comment: @MivaScott The intent is you don't do something like summon some nazghuls, which then "convince" ordinary people to help you out etc., so you are not allowed to use some strange loopholes to exlist the help of actual humanoids, be it by being persuasive or bending their will

Comment: What is the rules on summons your summons summoned?

Comment: @Daveman Anything summoned by your summons by... (and so on) is fine, as long as it is not of the creature type humanoid.

Comment: Are illusions allowed? Or does this need to be a real choir?

Comment: @linksassin only actual cratures / things. So the servants in a magnificent mansion would count if they would be able to sing, a casting of minor illusion not so much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So assuming your DM is running the spells in your favor, so that conjure animals conjures exactly what you want, and that when you duplicate a spell with wish, you duplicate it at as if cast at 8th level.

Pickup ring of wishing, reproduce Conjure animals at level 7, (or 9 if they allow, but we will work under 7) so you summon 24 giant owls. You order them to grab rings and summon their own giant owls, which they order to grab rings and summon their own giant owls... (Giant owls are special as they have language, so they can verbally command their own summons)

When your owls have cast their conjure animals so are concentrating, they then use their actions to grab rings and duplicate planar ally, having the new ally then join in and start a new chain of conjured animals.

Every round the group will increase by 24x for the initial wave, but any already concentrating creatures will instead double their number instead.

You might also knock off a minute or two off creating a large sign / contract for summoned planar allies that they can pickup as much gold as they desire if they follow the directions. Also possibly a sign informing the conjured giant owls of a greater power to seek the planar allies from.

Create one copy of your music, toward the end use wish rings to duplicate "Creation", if allowed to upcast at 8th level, it can produce a 20ft cube of perforated copies of the music. A foot deep will be about 3000 sheets, so 20ft = 60,000 layers. If you can make the music fit on 6x6 inch sheets there would be 40x40 sheets per layer for a total of 96 million copies of the music. (since it can be vegetable matter it will last 24 hour)

I honestly can't be bothered to figure out the actual number of creatures you would end up with. But suffice to say you should be able to pack out any facility with them. (my napkin math puts us at like 8 million creatures after 30 seconds). Even if you discount the planar allies (as non-summons) timing your conjure creatures to begin your concentration say 55 minutes before the performance will result in an absolutely absurd number of singing owls.

BTW I tried to do a conservative estimate (multiplying each round by 23 to accommodate losing the concentrating owls each round) Excel gave up after 227 rounds  (22 minutes) at 5.6298E+307, or 5 with 307 zeros after it. For comparison a Trillion is 12 zeros. I think the actual limit here would be physical space as the owls have to be summoned within 60ft of the summoner. so getting creatures back and forth to the rings of wishing would prove logistically challenging.

Comment: Does each owl need a ring of wishes? From where is the assumption of a never ending supply of 'ring of wishes'  *Feats and Magic Items are available as needed ... Unlimited money* turning into "infinite ring of wishes" seems to me a reach, but maybe that is an issue for the problem statement

Comment: Infinite rings of three wishes indeed seems very excessive.

Comment: "as needed" would indicate as many were available "as needed"

Comment: If you want to set a reasonable limit on magic items that is perfectly fine. But the prompt said they were "as needed" this scenario needed a lot.

Comment: I'm aware, just didn't expect this much cheese xD
Let's keep it and see if other answers come up with less wasteful means ;)

Comment: @TobiasF. Infinite money can buy infinite cheese. I'd expect more, if I were you.

Comment: You still need to figure out how you give each owl their the rings of wishes.

Comment: If you assume you find a spot in the elemental plane of air with perfectly still air and filled with with rings of wishes, you can expand the sphere containing all owls at 60' of movement + 60' range of conjure animal per round. Or is it 60' + 60' of movement + 60' of spell range per two rounds? Anyway, that gives you the expansion speed. Then you need to figure out how much space a giant owl needs in order to sing in the choir. Then you simply get the volume of this sphere.

Comment: Also you should wish very hard, that the DM does not invoke thermodynamics, because the insides of this Sphere of Owls is going to get very hot from all the body heat, and bake the birds. If the DM wants this kind of verisimilitude, then you need to estimate the thickness of habitable crust of this owl sphere, and get the number of actually living owls from its volume.