# Can a character Attack and Dash in one turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, movement, attack

Is Dashing and Attacking in the same turn possible without using a Bonus action? Everything I'm reading indicates a dash takes an entire turn and the entirety of the move.

Comment: When you say Bonus Actions aside, do you mean ignoring things like the rogue's ability "Cunning Action"?

Comment: Yes, ignoring things like Cunning Action.

Comment: Can a character with a movement rate of 30 decide not to dash the full 60 and, say, dash 40 feet and then attack within the same turn?

Comment: That's a different question, about breaking up movement. Try searching for it and I bet it's already answered.

Comment: @LordAo It sounds like you are asking about using less dash so that you can attack, in which case the answer is no. Dash just grants you additional movement not taking it is your choice but leftover movement doesn't grant additional options.

Comment: Regarding your parenthetical math: beware that Dash does not *multiply* movement, it *adds* to movement. That works out the same with one Dash, but [it makes a big difference with multiple Dash actions](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57340/how-far-does-a-rogue-move-when-dashing-twice-using-cunning-action).

Comment: How can the question fold in the comments here, and in the comments in the accepted answer, to improve the question for posterity?

Comment: @Korvin For a start I've removed the parenthetical, which was unnecessary anyway

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**Fighters can**. Action surge means you can use one action to dash, and the other to attack. Using action surge is a feature, and does not require a bonus action.

Outside of that feature...

Bonus actions aside seems to be a weird stipulation to put on this being that that is pretty much the only way you could both dash and attack.

You move on your turn, and you are allowed to take 1 action. (**PHB pg. 192**). One of those actions could be **Dash** which gives you additional movement on your turn. Basically you are converting your action into additional movement.

However, you can break up your movement as much as you wish (**PHB pg. 190**), and can **Action** during that move (which is an attack in the case you listed). So you can definitely move AND attack, but you cannot dash and attack without using a bonus action to grant either of those things.

Comment: This is what I'm looking for.  I was misunderstanding the nature of the movement within a turn.

Comment: Yeah, it took my group a while to understand the nature of movement as many of them cut their teeth on 4e which has a different movement situation.

Comment: We're 2E guys. :D

Comment: We were understanding a dash as its own move when a Dash is an action (like an attack) added to a move.

Comment: @LordAo It's a very fine distinctions people miss - a Dash doesn't actually make the character move, it just increases the total *allowed* movement for the turn.

Comment: Perhaps add the haste spell, it gives an extra action. And I believe there are some boots that give haste aswell. EDIT: nvm I see the Answer below already mentions it.

Answer (score 6):

Leaving aside spells and class features that allow dashing as a bonus action, the Haste spell would allow a character to use the Attack action and Dash action on the same turn, and a fighter's Action Surge would allow a full Attack action and a Dash action.

A sorcerer could also quicken either Booming Blade or Green Flame Blade to make an attack as a bonus action, leaving their action open for dashing, but I'm not sure if that also violates your premise.

Comment: "Full Attack Action" is a holdover term from prior editions; there's no such animal in 5E. It's just an "Attack Action". There are class features that can modify the definition of an "Attack Action," but the name does not change.

Comment: "fully allow an Attack Action," or "complete Attack Action" would be equivalent meanings to what I said.

Comment: No, they would not. Usage of "full", "fully", or "complete" implies that there is some way to get a "fractional" or "partial" Attack Action. An Attack Action is atomic, you either take one, or you don't. What a character can do *during* that singular Attack Action can be redefined by class feature.

Comment: Haste, which I use in my first example, allows for a restricted Attack action. The Attack action granted by Action Surge has no such restriction, and thus my word choice.

Answer (score 1):

The Charger feat allows you to dash and attack with a +5 to attack damage, or shove a creature 10 feet

Comment: As a bonus action. I believe the asker wants to keep his bonus action.