# How much can I move if I don't attack?

Tags: dnd-5e, monk, rogue

I'm playing an Aarakocra Rogue 2/Monk 3 and I'm confused as to how much I am able to move as they both have Dash and Disengage bonus actions.

I know I can't use more then one bonus action in a round of combat.

Could I use the Cunning Action of the Rogue then move my full movement and not attack?

On the other hand can I use a Ki point to get my extra attack?

I am VERY confused please help!!

Comment: This is a [related question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57340/22566).  Does that answer your question on movement?  I think you should ask the Ki point/extra attack for this as a separate question, since your move question doesn't include an attack. With no attack, you don't get an extra attack.

Comment: @Liam One other thing. Can you confirm if your question is related to the situation you posited in the post (i.e. Cunning Action and then full movement) or if you're looking to maximize your movement. To clarify, the former is a question about a specific course of action, the latter is a question about the best way to do something given certain constraints.

Answer (score 8):

Aarakocra have a base speed of 25' walking or 50' flying (Elemental Evil pp5). 
As a Monk wearing no Armor you gain Unarmored Movement and an additional 10' of movement (PHB pp78). This brings your base speed up to 35' walking or 60' flying.

If you don't attack, you can take the Dash action for a total of either 70' walking or 120' flying.

If you use your bonus action for Cunning Action and Dash again, you may move a total of 105' walking or 180' flying.

Your Ki point options are all bonus actions, which are no longer available after you've used your bonus action as a Cunning Action. Therefore, you would NOT be able to attack if you moved, Dashed and Bonus Action-Cunning Action Dashed again.

Your choices are:

Move(35/60), attack, bonus action Ki point usage

Move(35/60), cunning action dash(35/60), attack

Move(35/60), dash(35/60), cunning action dash(35/60)

Comment: monks gain an additional bonus to speed when not wearing armor. consider including that in this answer

Comment: @THiebert Thank you! I missed the Unarmored Movement :)