# Does a ring of jumping let you jump farther than your normal movement?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, movement

The *ring of jumping*'s description says, "While wearing this ring, you can cast the *jump* spell from it as a bonus action at will, but can target only yourself when you do so." And the *jump* spell says, "The creature's jump distance is tripled until the spell ends."

By way of comparison, the *boots of striding and springing* specifically says, "[Y]ou can jump three times the normal distance, though you can't jump farther than your remaining movement would allow."

It would seem the *boots* are far superior (despite both being uncommon items), since the *boots* don't require a bonus action to use, have no set duration, and also give some other benefits like normal speed when encumbered. That is, *unless* the *ring* allows for exceeding normal movement on a jump, in which case the *ring* may be a better choice (at least for jumping).

So, to repeat, does a *ring of jumping* let the wearer jump farther than the wearer's normal movement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens when you run out of movement while jumping?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57165/what-happens-when-you-run-out-of-movement-while-jumping)

Comment: I disagree on the duplicate call. This question seems to be specifically asking if the Jump Spell allows you to bypass the normal limit on your jumping distance (your Speed). So, the question appears to be asking if the specific ruling of the Jump spell overrides the general ruling of Long Jumping.

Comment: @guildsbounty the answer in the linked question contains that answer.

Comment: @NautArch But duplicate voting is based on whether the question is the same. Many questions have the same answers, (e.g., “talk to your players” is the answer to many different questions), but they are still distinct questions.

Comment: (On [further discussion](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/37198175#37198175), I'd still personally say that these are closely related but separate, but it's such a close call that I wouldn't stake anything on it.)

Answer (score 9):

**Jump does not let you bypass the 'Speed' restraint on jumping. But the ring is still useful**

As to Jump (and the boots) not increasing your speed, here is some Developer commentary on the matter, specifically addressing these effects.

> Question posed: "Can you jump farther than your movement when using magic i.e spell Jump & boots of striding and springing?"
>
> To be clear, things like the jump spell don't increase speed. You can jump crazy far, but your speed caps it. -Crawford
>
> Are you saying you can't jump farther than your speed even with Jump spell or Boots of Striding and Springing? -Followup Question Asked
>
> Every foot jumped costs movement, so you can jump farther than your current speed if you take the Dash action. -Crawford Again.

[Source](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/512336304231550976)

So, no. Neither the Jump spell nor the Boots of Striding and Springing allow you to exceed your total Speed in distance jumped, though taking the Dash action allows you to move your full Speed a second time during the turn, effectively increasing your Speed by 2x for the round. This lets you actually get some use out of your massively boosted jumping distance. This would rather plainly imply that the Boots of Striding and Springing are generally superior to a Ring of Jumping.

Where this is not true is when you start combining magic items. For example, if you get your hands on a pair of Boots of Speed. Naturally, you can't wear two pairs of boots...but you can wear a pair of boots and a ring. This combination takes two bonus actions to fire up, but then you have a full minute of doubled running speed and tripled jumping distance, without having to take the Dash Action. And because you can get 10 minutes of boosted speed from the boots per day, you can do this 10 times a day. So you have all the mobility of someone Dashing around in Boots of Striding and Springing, but still have your Action free to use.

So, taken in isolation, it does appear that the Boots of Striding and Springing are generally superior to a Ring of Jumping. However, you have 10 fingers for ring-wearing, but can only wear one pair of boots. So the ring is better for combination work.

Comment: *“Dashing allows you to temporarily double your movement speed”* could use some rephrasing since it's likely to mislead readers, since [Dash works additively, not multiplicatively](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57340/how-far-does-a-rogue-move-when-dashing-twice-using-cunning-action).

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Edited...better?

Comment: Yes, that's nice and clear, and even better, touches on the common source of confusion without dwelling on it overmuch. A very nice edit!