# Are jumping modifiers applied before or after jumping multipliers?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, movement

Two features (a Champion Fighter's level 7 Remarkable Athlete, and a Thief Rogue's level 3 Second Story Work) give a modifier to long jump distance.

Three features (the Jump spell, the Boots of Striding and Springing and a Monk's level 2 Step of the Wind) give a multiplier to jump distance.

If a character is under the effect of both a jump modifier and a jump multiplier, how is the calculation done ?

For example, if a Champion with a Strength of 20 and under the effect of a Jump spell makes a running long jump, would his total long jump distance be :

1) 65 feet [ (20 x 3) + 5 ]

2) 75 feet [ (20 + 5) x 3 ]

Comment: related: [Combining Jump and Step of the Wind](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/57283)

Comment: Related: [How are numerical bonuses combined?](//rpg.stackexchange.com/q/83663)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There are no rules but 65 feet makes the most sense

Jump

> You touch a creature. The creature's jump distance is tripled until the spell ends.

Remarkable Athlete

> **when you make a running long jump**, the distance you can cover increases by a number of feet equal to your Strength modifier

### Chronological order

The bonus to jump should follow the order in which the bonuses are actually applied in the game. In other words, since you apply the spell *before* you jump, your jumping distance is tripled first. Then, when you actually do a running long jump, the *remarkable athlete* bonus gets added onto that.

Thus, the math follows the order in which the bonuses are actually applied.

### Constant versus situational bonus

Another way to reach the same conclusion is to think of the two effects in terms of how general they are. While under the effects of *jump*, your jump distance is constantly tripled. However, *remarkable athlete* only gives you the bonus to jump when you are actually making a running long jump. If you make a standing long jump you don't get any bonus at all from *remarkable athlete*, but *jump* still applies.

I would argue the constant general effect gets applied, and then the situational bonus gets added on top of that.

**Either way you think about it, the math would work out to:
(20 x 3) + 5 = 65 feet**

---

#### Note regarding jumping and speed

The distance you jump is indeed limited by your speed but with dashing and other means of speed increases the jump distances can be kept relevant as indicated in this conversation with [Jeremy Crawford](https://twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/512336304231550976):

> Q: Can you jump farther than your movement when using magic i.e spell
> Jump & boots of striding and springing?
>
> A: To be clear, things like the jump spell don't increase speed. You
> can jump crazy far, but your speed caps it.
>
> Q: Are you saying you can't jump farther than your speed even with
> Jump spell or Boots of Striding and Springing?
>
> A: Every foot jumped costs movement, so you can jump farther than your
> current speed if you take the Dash action.

This is discussed more here [Does a ring of jumping let you jump farther than your normal movement?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/99364/does-a-ring-of-jumping-let-you-jump-farther-than-your-normal-movement) and [What happens when you run out of movement while jumping?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/57165/what-happens-when-you-run-out-of-movement-while-jumping)

Answer (score 2):

I would apply the addition first, then the multiplier.  In much the same way as if you have an addition to your movement (e.g. barbarian or monk, or Mobile feat), and you double your movement somehow (e.g. *Haste*), the entire movement gets doubled.  So, your #2: 75 feet [ (20 + 5) x 3 ] seems right to me.

Remember that, RAW, your jump is still limited by your total movement, so it may not matter whether the jump works out to 65' or 75', if you don't have enough movement to cover both the runup, and that jumping distance.